# Nginx how to return 404 when access index.php directly

Tags: php, nginx

For security purpose, I am attempting to hide almost all the fingerprint info of my web application. The most important thing is to hide `PHP` from any visitors. So I try to modify my `Nginx`'s configuration file. The configuration will show as follows.

```
location / {
        root   /data/site/public;

        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri /index.php;

        location /index.php {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }
```

By this way, I successfully hide `index.php` from URL. However, Hackers could also directly access my website by using some URL such as `http://example.com/index.php`, which shows that my website is written by `PHP`. Sometimes it maybe dangerous.
So, I modify the `Nginx`'s config second time, longing for `404` when access `index.php` directly, and it looks like

```
location / {
        root   /data/site/public;

        if ( $request_uri ~ /index\.php ) {
            return 404;
        }

        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri /index.php;

        location /index.php {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }
```

However..., it seems that `Nginx` acts nothing different from the previous one.

Could anyone tell me the reason ? or any other solutions...

Comment: Did you think about renaming `index.php` to something like `veryWeirdAndLongName.php`? Or you can check in the script by itself if its name is in the requested URI

Comment: Good solution, but I am not a programer of this application, it means that I could not modify the original app directly. Further more, I wonder the explanation why the last configuration make nothing difference. ^.^